# Spreadsheet to multiple txt files with specified names

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, openoffice-calc, export-to-text

I'm looking for a way to export text from a cells in a spreadsheet into multiple '.txt' files. The trick is that each .txt file would contain text from one cell from specified column and it would be named using text from one cell from other specified column.

Example Spreadsheet:

```
Names   text    extra-info
John    15684   Spring
Sally   54645   Autumn
Mark    45545   Winter
```

From this example three .txt files should be created. 
Named:
    John.txt
    Sally.txt
    Mark.txt

and containing relevant numbers. ex 15684  inside Jonh.txt.

The spreadsheet is a google spreadsheet at the moment but we have access to open office and excel as long as one of them can do that job.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear what the question is. Have you hit a specific roadblock with your code?

Comment: Hi HDCerberus. It's not problem with code, more like a roadblock before I start. I am looking for the way to do it. I have no programming background. I posted the message to get an idea, how hard is it to make it and were to look to try find more answers. Paul seams to give me nice stuff to start with :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty straightforward. Do you know how to begin writing an App Script? I don't mean to sound condescending, but since you didn't post code, I don't know exactly where you need help.

I'd use the Spreadsheet service to gather the data from your spreadsheet:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()

Then you'd iterate through each row and create a new file using the createFile() method in DriveApp for the contents:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String,String)

All of the resulting files will be in the root folder of Drive.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I will have a look on those. You are right about my capabilities of coding. I have no idea how to do it. But at least now I have some start and I know what should I type to google it up :)

If you have any other comments it would be much appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. Look for some sample code on Google, then dive in and post back here if you need any more help. Good luck!